# Black screen when opening app after a few hours of inactivity

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am working on a minimal open-source Launcher ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_desktop_application_launchers)) for Android.

When I run it on a phone, put that on standby and unlock it after 4 - 6 hours, all I get is a black screen.

**I hope this has some general solution** and is not only caused by my code.
That way answers to this question will also be useful to everyone else on here.

**Relevant mentions for my code**

In the [Android Manifest XML](https://github.com/finnmglas/Launcher/blob/master/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml) I declared the main activity to be a launcher (home screen). The main activity ([MainActivity.kt](https://github.com/finnmglas/Launcher/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/finnmglas/launcher/MainActivity.kt)) has an `onCreate` function, only refreshes a clock and checks for some `OnTouch` events. The full project code can also be seen [on GitHub](https://github.com/finnmglas/Launcher).

[Go to the related issue on Github](https://github.com/finnmglas/Launcher/issues/9).

Comment: I don't know the whole solution but please check if battery management is not shutting your app and you have right access level like other launchers have.

Comment: @Raushan thank you I checked all of that. I got all the necessary permissions, and set `CATEGORY_HOME` in the Manifest for it to be a home application/ launcher. I am running some further tests over this night and I think I get it fixed with the help of that data from the tests. Thank you for that comment!

Comment: Seems like neither `onStart()` nor `onCreate()` are called when I unlock the phone after long inactivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try implementing `onResume()` if you haven't already. It is possible that the app has not stopped and as such `onStart()` would not be called when you unlock your phone.

Where an app has paused, it would just call `onResume()` instead. You can try putting your code here to recreate the views as needed. You can also save any relevant user information in `onPause()` and reload it in `onResume()`. This will allow you to preserve a consistent user experience and avoid memory leaks caused by, for example, referring to objects that no longer exist.

Let me know if it works, good luck.

[The Activity Lifecycle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVidz.png)

Comment: Thank you for the answer - it definitely is worth trying. I am running lots of tests at the moment. It certainly is an issue the Activity Lifecycle of my `MainActivity()`. I'll let you know once I get it fixed ^^

Comment: I got it all fixed, it was a little more complex than this but very helpful. Got the app published ^^ https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.finnmglas.launcher